# Install header file of R package

Tags: c++, r, cmake

I am working on an R package with the following directory structure at the root:

```
CMakeLists.txt
configure
configure.win
NAMESPACE
DESCRIPTION
README
src
cmake
examples
man
R
```

I build and install like so :

```
R CMD build . 
R CMD INSTALL mypackage*.tar.gz -l /home/myname/Rlibs/
```

This installs the `.so` file into my installation directory, but I'd also like to install some of the header files of the package in my installation area. The header files are in the `'src'` folder with the `.h` extension. I can't find a way to do that. Can someone help? BTW As you might see from the directory listing I'm using `cmake`.

**Edit :** 
The configure file in the root directory looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash -e

set -x

unset CXX
unset CC

which cmake
cmake --version
cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="`pwd`/_install" -DCMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX_CXX=""
cmake --build _builds --config Release --target install

mv _install/lib/mypackage.so src/mypackage.so || echo -n ""
```

The CMakeLists.txt in the root directory :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(mypackage)

if(NOT MSVC)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
endif()


if(MSVC AND MYPACKAGE_DISABLE_AUTOLINK)
  add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1)
endif()

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")

add_subdirectory(src)
```

And the CMakeLists.txt in the `src` directory :

```
include(GenerateExportHeader)

include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}") 

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED filesystem system regex log thread date_time chrono)
find_package(GDAL REQUIRED)

if(NOT WIN32)
  add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1)
endif()  

add_library(
    mypackage
    SHARED
    SomeAlgo.cpp
    SomeAlgo.h
    MyParam.h
    SomeList.cpp
    SomeList.h
)
generate_export_header(mypackage)

target_include_directories(mypackage PUBLIC "${R_INCLUDE_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(mypackage "${R_LIBRARIES}")

install(TARGETS mypackage DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES SomeList.h DESTINATION include) # <-- I added this
```

**Edit 2** 
I get this output from R CMD INSTALL

```
* installing *source* package ‘mypackage’ ...
+ unset CXX
+ unset CC
+ which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
+ cmake --version
cmake version 3.0.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
++ pwd
+ cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/RtmpSaU3wb/R.INSTALL761c2555d904/mypackage/_install -DCMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX_CXX=
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_INLINE_VISIBILITY - Success
.....
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/RtmpSaU3wb/R.INSTALL761c2555d904/mypackage/_builds
+ cmake --build _builds --config Release --target install
Scanning dependencies of target mypackage_fpredict
[  3%] Building CXX object src/mypackage/CMakeFiles/mypackage_fpredict.dir/__/OpusReader.cpp.o
....
[100%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/mypackage.dir/mypackage/RBackend.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library mypackage.so
[100%] Built target mypackage
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /tmp/RtmpSaU3wb/R.INSTALL761c2555d904/mypackage/_install/lib/mypackage.so
-- Removed runtime path from "/tmp/RtmpSaU3wb/R.INSTALL761c2555d904/mypackage/_install/lib/mypackage.so"
+ mv _install/lib/mypackage.so src/mypackage.so
+ echo -n ''
** libs
** arch -
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
installing to /home/myname/Rlibs/mypackage/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (mypackage)
```

Only the .so file ends up in /home/myname/Rlibs/mypackage/libs/, there's no include directory or header file. However I see the include directory in the temporary build directory (added a `ls` to the configure to see it). So basically the problem is to move the include directory from the temporary build directory to my `Rlibs` area

Comment: You want the headers to end up in `/home/myname/Rlibs/` or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, something like  `/home/myname/Rlibs/mypackage/`

Comment: OK, so can you post for us the section of your `CMakeLists.txt` which builds the `.tar.gz` file?

Comment: i just edited my post

Comment: So does it end up putting `SomeList.h` into the `include` directory?

Comment: I added more info to my post

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so R CMD INSTALL checks if there is a directory called "inst" and installs files or directories in that directory into the library installation path. In the R package I'm working on this "inst" package doesn't exist so I create it on the fly when compiling with cmake under the temporary build directory, so I modified the configure file :

```
#!/bin/bash -e

set -x

unset CXX
unset CC

which cmake
cmake --version
cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="`pwd`/_install" -DCMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX_CXX=""
cmake --build _builds --config Release --target install

## Added two lines below ##
mkdir inst
mv  _install/include inst

mv _install/lib/mypackage.so src/mypackage.so || echo -n ""
```

and finally I get `/home/myname/Rlibs/mypackage/include/SomeList.h`